# assign hyperlink to cell in google sheets to google drive files using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a GAS that extracts file names and google drive hyperlinks from a folder and pastes them into google sheets.

Now I want to create google drive hyperlinks to a selected range in google sheets based on the file names(file names are accurately extracted using a different GAS) with its cell position maintained. Can someone supplement here or guide me to reference?

Requirement:

- selecting a range of cells and searching for "matching" file names recursively in the folders
- I have folder and subfolders so the script would have to navigate/search multi-level folders.
- The depth of the folders are about 3-4 levels

Below is the current working GAS

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c=s.getActiveCell();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("<id>");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var names=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    names.push([str]);
  }
  s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length).setFormulas(names);
}
```

Spreadsheet sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are the folder names and filenames on a sheet in the Spreadsheet.

   - These folders and files are in the specific folder.
   - Each name is the unique name in all values.
2. You select the ranges. For example, it's "A1:D12" in the Spreadsheet of your image.
3. You want to retrieve all file names and search the files using the filenames.
4. You want to replace the retrieved values to the formulas of hyperlinks of the files.

From your replying and additional information, I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

After you set the folder ID, please select the range (for example, "A1:D12") and run the function of `myFunction()`. By this, the filenames are replaced to the formulas of hyperlinks.

```
function myFunction() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c = s.getActiveRange()
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var values = c.getValues();
  var getFiles = function getFiles(folder) {
    var folders = folder.getFolders();
    while(folders.hasNext()) {
      var fol = folders.next();
//      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
//        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
//          values[i][j] = values[i][j] == fol.getName() ? ('=hyperlink("' + fol.getUrl() + '","' + fol.getName() + '")') : values[i][j];
//        }
//      }
      getFiles(fol);
    }
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var f = files.next();
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          values[i][j] = values[i][j] == f.getName() ? ('=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")') : values[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }(fldr);
  if (values.length > 0) {
    s.getRange(c.getRow(), c.getColumn(), values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- When the following lines, which are commented above, are used, the hyperlinks of folders are also put.

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      values[i][j] = values[i][j] == fol.getName() ? ('=hyperlink("' + fol.getUrl() + '","' + fol.getName() + '")') : values[i][j];
    }
  }
  ```
- If the same filenames and folder names are existing in the cell values and in subfolders, the logic for parsing the folders and files from the cell values is required. In your additional image, I cannot understand about the logic. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike-apologies if my requirements were unclear. I added a requirement above. I need to select a range of cells and then have the app search for any matching filenames in the folders/subfolders and attach a hyperlink to the location.

Comment: @Hachi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike-thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, its giving me an error `The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 23, file "updated_recursive_tanaike")` Please also see a sample of my spreadsheet above.

Comment: @Hachi Thank you for replying. From your error message, I thought that `names.length` might be `0`. So I modified the script. Could you please test it again?

Comment: @Hachi By the way, about your additional information, where cell do you select?

Comment: @Tanaike-I select the cells folder1 to file4 (there are blank cells in range) for example. Column selection is also fine if that’s easier.

Comment: @Hachi Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I could understand that from your replying and additional image, my 1st sample script is not suitable for your goal. So I updated the script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you want, I apologize, again.

Comment: @Tanaike-Thank you for all the update and its also my fault my direction was not clear. Really appreciate the time and effort here! All worked sound.

Comment: @Hachi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also I think that your cooperation was useful for resolving your issue. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Recursing for hyperlinks in folders and subfolders**

```
function makeHyperlinks() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Your Starting Folder Id');//The main folder to start in  
  var obj={id:ss.getId(),sheetname:'hyperlinks'};//spreadsheet info to pass to recursive function
  getFnF(folder,obj);
}
```

This function recurses through the folders and subfolders appending all of the hyperlinks into the spreadsheet as it goes.

```
function getFnF(folder,obj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(obj.id);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(obj.sheetname);
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    sh.appendRow(['=hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '","' + file.getName() + '")']);
  }
  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    getFnF(subfolder,obj);
  }
}
```

[Recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion)

Comment: @Cooper-really appreciate the help but I have the cells in the fixed location and attach the hyperlink. Your app does work but lists all them in a new column which I do not want. I want everything in the same position before and after.