# How to search contents of files in all folders and subfolders of google drive in Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to search the contents of files through all folders and subfolders in my google drive. Currently I am only able to search files in my Root directory.  How to I expand this into searching all files?

```
function testSearch(){
    // Log the name of every file that contains a certain string
    // you can get the folder of your choice here by its ID or by its name, in the second case the returned object is a folder iterator so you will have to iterate its content. There are examples all around on how to do that.
      var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Search");
      var idList = ['GS 4-20', 'GS 10-3', '1232.3', '1234.3', '5111.5', '3211.1','3211.3', 'GS 10-16', 'GS 93-23', '2311.3', '2321.5', 'GS 10-15', '3212.4', '3212.5', '2322.5', 'GS 10T 25', 'GS 8-4', 'GS 6-21', 'GS 4-13', '1234.3', '1234.4', '3212.4', 'S 1-8', 'S 6-1', 'S 3-4', 'S 4-2', 'S 15-8', '1122.3', '1132.1', '1313.2', '2113.5', '2114.2', '2133.4', '2224.3', '2321.3', '2332.2'];      //var myQuery = "fullText contains '4-13'"
      for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
      var myQuery = "fullText contains \"" + idList[i] + "\"";
      var filesoutput = files.searchFiles(myQuery);
        while (filesoutput.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          var fileName = file.getName();
          //var fileURL = file.getUrl();
          var fileURL = file.getId();
          Logger.log(file.getName());
          activeSpreadsheet.appendRow([fileName, fileURL]);
          //}
      }
      //function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
MailApp.sendEmail("EMAIL@EMAIL.com", "TEXT","The Search has completed",{ htmlBody: "The Search has completed" });
```

Comment: Try using recursion.  Here's and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59817521/7215091)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google apps script - iterate folder and subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069823/google-apps-script-iterate-folder-and-subfolder)